# Distinct values in columns X per Distinct values in column Y

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following query to sort out data in my table and it is not calculating properly:

```
SELECT rowid, customer, category, SUM(DISTINCT return) as returntotal, SUM(DISTINCT release) as releasetotal FROM orders GROUP BY customer
```

and here is my current table:

[image]

and this is what I need the query result to be:

[image]

I need the SUM of the DISTINCT values in 'return', by DISTINCT 'category'; the SUM of DISTINCT values in 'release' by DISTINCT 'category' and all GROUPED BY customer. My current query is skipping the DISTINCT categories that have the same values. For example: In rowid 17-19 in the top image my query results in a value of '465' for Scott, where the value I need is the DISTINCT value per DISTINCT category or 465 for Home Goods and 465 for Lawn.

My output for each row should be as follows:

```
customer (no duplicates)     totalreturn     totalrelease
```

Here is an example of the desired output on each row:

```
Scott       $0      $930
Michelle    $123    $250
Brad        $2070   $0
```

Questions:

1. What should my statement look like to produce the results I need?
2. Is using GROUPED BY overkill if Im already using DISTINCT??

Thanks!

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your final result, use a subquery:

```
select customer, sum(return) as return, sum(category) as category
from (select distinct customer, return, release, category
      from orders
     ) o
group by customer;
```

Now that I've said that, I think you have a problem with your underlying data.  Whenever you might be considering `sum(distinct)` or `count(distinct)`, you have a data problem.  I assume, in this case, that the data is intentionally denormalized by category in the `orders` table.  You really should be getting the common values for each category from a different table.  Or, you have duplicates in `orders` that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Gordon. I think Ill recheck my import (my data is coming from a .csv file) and see if I can normalize the grouping there on INSERT.